# Cannot access to the webconsole interface

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

Since few days, I am playing around with apache felix. Everything works fine as it can be seen when lauching the lb command:

```
START LEVEL 2
   ID|State      |Level|Name
    0|Active     |    0|System Bundle (4.0.3)
    1|Active     |    2|Apache Felix Bundle Repository (1.6.6)
    2|Active     |    2|Apache Felix Configuration Admin Service (1.6.0)
    3|Active     |    2|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.12.0)
    4|Active     |    2|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.10.0)
    5|Active     |    2|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.10.0)
    6|Active     |    2|Apache Felix Http Bundle (2.2.0)
    7|Active     |    2|Apache Felix iPOJO (1.8.6)
    8|Active     |    2|Apache Felix iPOJO OSGi Junit Runner (1.0.0)
    9|Active     |    2|Apache Felix Shell Service (1.4.3)
   10|Active     |    2|Apache Felix Web Management Console (3.1.8)
   11|Installed  |    3|[Optimacs/OSGi] DataService - Hello World (1.1.0)
   12|Active     |    2|[Optimacs/OSGi] DataService Model (0.4.1.SNAPSHOT)
   13|Active     |    2|[Optimacs/OSGi] DataService Network API (0.4.1.SNAPSHOT)
   14|Active     |    2|[Optimacs/OSGi] DataService Container (0.4.1.SNAPSHOT)
```

According to this list, I can use the web management console. To this aim I have set the org.osgi.service.http.port option to 8080.
My problem occurs when I open my browser (Chrome, the latest version) and try accessing to the web console (`url = http://localhost:8080/system/console`). I get an error 102 (connection refused).
Is there any particular configuration step I have missed?

**EDIT**

Running `inspect cap service` through the gogo shell reports the following about the HttpService:

```
org.apache.felix.http.bundle [6] provides:
------------------------------------------
service; javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet with properties:
   http.felix.dispatcher = org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet
   service.description = Dispatcher for bridged request handling
   service.id = 20
   service.vendor = The Apache Software Foundation
service; java.util.EventListener with properties:
   http.felix.dispatcher = org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.EventDispatcher
   service.description = Dispatcher for bridged HttpSession events
   service.id = 21
   service.vendor = The Apache Software Foundation
```

There is no indication about the used port unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm, nothing obvious is missing. I wonder if the HttpService is present, could you do `inspect cap service` from the shell and scan through for HttpService? If it's there it should also report what port number it is using.

Comment: @NeilBartlett I have editted my post taking your comment into consideration.

Comment: I was looking for information about `HttpService`, not `HttpServlet`.

Comment: @NeilBartlett Your comment helps me pointing out what was missing. Actually the http.bundle is not sufficient and org.apache.felix.http.jetty-2.2.0.jar must be installed as well.

Comment: Alternatively you could give https://github.com/evandor/skysail-webconsole a try, it should start up without any problems (at least that is the idea ;) - it is still in early alpha).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved thanks to Neil's comment:

> I wonder if the HttpService is present, could you do inspect cap service from the shell and scan through for HttpService? If it's there it should also report what port number it is using.